# I used Glide library to load image into imageView and I don't know how to make image pinch to zoomable

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-glide

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    //Variables
    ImageView imageView;
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    //Loading into ImageView
    Glide.with(this)
            .load("http://vrijeme.hr/bradar.gif")
            .into(imageView);
}
```

I tried using Picasso too and then connecting it with PhotoView library but it  didn't do anything, when I tried pinch to zoom it didn't zoom at all, here is part of that code:

```
ImageView imageView;
PhotoViewAttacher photoView;

imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
photoView = new PhotoViewAttacher(imageView);
Picasso.with(this)
       .load("link")
       .resize(1080,80)
       .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can for example use this library.
https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView

Load your image into this widget, instead of ImageView

Sample usage:

```
private TouchImageView mContentView;
private private SimpleTarget target;

mContentView = (TouchImageView) findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);

target = new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
   public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap, GlideAnimation glideAnimation) 
{
            // do something with the bitmap
            // for demonstration purposes, let's just set it to an ImageView
            mContentView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    };



    Glide.with(this) // could be an issue!
            .load( imagePath )
            .asBitmap()
            .into(target);
```

Notice, that i also use SimpleTarget first, it is good practice for using Glide and pinch to zoom effect for large images.

And the layout will be something like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.FullscreenActivity">


<com.yourPath.TouchImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Also, sometimes there is an issue with loading the image after this setup.
For me works something like this.
I override the method from TouchImageView class:

```
@Override
public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
    imageRenderedAtLeastOnce = false;
    super.setImageBitmap(bm);
    savePreviousImageValues();
    fitImageToView();
}
```

Comment: I added "imageRenderedAtLeastOnce = false;" into "setImageBitmap" method of my custom zoomableimageviews class and its working fine. Thanks @Konrad...

Answer (score 22):

This library here called `PhotoView` is quite popular. 
https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

With 13,500+ stars, 30+ contributors backing it, so many people using it and how easy it is to integrate into a project, it almost feels like a standard.

It's also compatible with `Glide` ^.^

---

**Installation** (Official documentation by [chrisbanes](https://github.com/chrisbanes))

Add this in your root `build.gradle` file (**not** your module `build.gradle` file):

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Then, add the library to your module `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:latest.release.here'
}
```

At that time of writing, `latest.release.here` is `2.1.4`.

---

**Usage** (Official documentation by [chrisbanes](https://github.com/chrisbanes))

There is a [sample](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView/tree/master/sample) provided which shows how to use the library in a more advanced way, but for completeness, here is all that is required to get PhotoView working:

```
<com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView
    android:id="@+id/photo_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

```
PhotoView photoView = (PhotoView) findViewById(R.id.photo_view);
photoView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
```

That's it!

---

**Usage with [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)**

Nothing changes!!

```
PhotoView photoView = (PhotoView) findViewById(R.id.photo_view);
Glide.with(this).load(imageUrl).into(photoView);
```

Comment: Maybe it's ad but at least it works well with Glide. Good.

Comment: It is saved days. great framework. I think this is the more correct answer :)